# SQL query, how would you write a query to receive this answer?

Tags: sql

my teacher gave this question on a test. Myself and numerous classmates asked how to write the query but he haven't explained it.

I've read documentations and still haven't been able to figure it out

Here help and explanation is appreciated

what I have tried so far is :

```
SELECT Course.Name, Count(Student.ID)
FROM Course JOIN Student ON Course.ID = Student.Course_ID
ORDER BY Course.Name
```

[image]

Comment: (This seems suspiciously like homework) What have you tried so far?

Comment: You will need to know how to use: `OUTER JOIN`, `COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`. If you **really** want to learn I suggest working through  [SQL Zoo](https://sqlzoo.net/) tutorial or something similar.

Comment: @Error_2646 It wasn't homework. I updated the questions with what I tried before

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks for this resource I've reading books instead and w3school.

Comment: Just make sure that you are actually running queries that you write.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement would look like this

```
SELECT Course.Name, Count(Student.ID) AS COUNT_OF_STUDENTS_REGISTERED
FROM Course LEFT JOIN Student ON Course.ID = Student.Course_ID
GROUP BY Course.Name
ORDER BY Count(Student.ID) DESC, Course.Name;
```

Comment: I believe OP wanted some explanation on WHY this query yields the expected result.